# Invariant homogeneous polynomials by the action of SL are constant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory

It seems to be known that the only invariant homogeneous polynomials in $k[X_0,...,X_n]_d$ by the action of $SL(n+1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$, are the constants, ie, $F(gx)=F(x)$  for all  $x\in\mathbb{P}^n$, $g\in SL(n+1)$ iff $F(X_0,...,X_n)=ctt$.

I'm not able to find any proof. Any simple proof, or a reference where I can find it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The action of $SL_{n+1}$ on $k[X_0,X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is also induced by the action of $SL_{n+1}$ on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. Let $F$ be a homogeneous invariant of degree $d$ and let $v\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. I'll show that if $d\neq 0$, then $F(v)=0$.

Let $g\in SL_{n+1}$ such that the last entry of $g\cdot v$ is $0$ (try to show that such a $g$ always exists). Then, for $t\in\mathbb{C}^{\times}$, consider the diagonal matrix $$
h(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
t & & & \\
& \ddots & & \\
& & t &\\
& & & t^{-n}
\end{bmatrix}\in SL_{n+1}
$$ Note that $h(t)\cdot v=t v$ so we have $$
F(v)=F(h(t)v)=F(tv)=t^{d} F(v).
$$ Then, either $d=0$, or (as there exists $t$ such that $t^d\neq 1$) $F(v)=0$. As $v$ is chosen arbitrary, $F(v)=0$ implies that $F=0$. Thus, only invariants are constants.